# Clartiy DesignSystem How to center a spinner

Tags: vmware-clarity

How can I center a Spinner in the middle of the page?

```
<div class="content-area" *ngIf="!document">
  <div class="spinner">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

I try several combination of everything css-class with center in it, but did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox. Add a class to the content area that implements use of flexbox on its children and then center the item with justify-content and align-items.

Here is the markup I'm referring to:

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-area centered-content-area">
  <div class="spinner">Loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css to center the spinner:

```
.centered-content-area {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here is a stackblitz to see it working: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v3-light-theme-hhfttg